# Using JQuery rating stars and submitting data to analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, analytics

I am having some trouble implementing a JQuery star rating plugin. The plugin in question can be found at http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/

The trouble I'm having is passing the score off to Google analytics. I have managed to implement the plugin but for some reason the code will not fire the analytics custom event. The correct current value is alerted when the stars are clicked, which is the value I want to pass to the Google analytics event tracking.

Any help would be much appreciated, my code is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/styles.css"/>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.stars.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ui.stars.css"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = location.href;

    $(function ratingStars(){
        $("#ratings").stars({
            captionEl: $("#stars-cap"),
            oneVoteOnly: false,
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ui-stars-star').click(function() {
            // Retrieve instance
            var ui = $("#ratings").data("stars");
            var currValue = ui.options.value;
            //alert the currValue to make sure it is in place.
            alert(currValue);
           //send data to track
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'UATRatingTest', 'UATRatingTest2', url, currValue]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<div class="RatingStars">
    <form id="ratings">
        <input type="radio"  name="rate" value="1" title="Poor" id="rate1" />
        <input type="radio"  name="rate" value="2" title="Fair" id="rate2" /> 
        <input type="radio"  name="rate" value="3" title="Average" id="rate3" /> 
        <input type="radio"  name="rate" value="4" title="Good" id="rate4" /> 
        <input type="radio"  name="rate" value="5" title="Excellent" id="rate5" />
    </form>
<span style="margin-right:5px; margin-left:10px;"> Rating: </span> <span id="stars-cap"></span> <br/>
```

The plugin creates a

```
<div class="ui-stars-star">
```

for each star which is why I put a click function on it, to try and submit the score given.

If anyone has any previous experience with the plugin that would be great.

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. It appears the currValue was being parsed as a String, not an integer which is required by analytics to fire the script. I solved it by converting the value into an integer using the following code:

```
var myString = currValue;
var myConvertedInteger;
myConvertedInteger = parseInt(myString);
//Check string has been converted 
alert(myConvertedInteger);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'UATRatingTest', 'UATRatingTest2', url, myConvertedInteger]);
```

Thanks for your input Rory.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements with the `.ui-stars-star` class are being created dynamically try the `live()` method to hook up their events:

```
$('.ui-stars-star').live("click", function() { ...
```

Or, if you're using jQuery 1.7, you can use `on()`

```
$('.ui-stars-star').on("click", function() { ...
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that didn't make the analytics code fire. I dont think there is any problem with parsing the score, as the alert shows the right score. Its just something in the analytics doesnt fire. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem. Is there anything appearing in the console/Firebug relating to a failure in the google AJAX call?

Comment: No unfortunately not, the there is no errors in the script panel, just the custom event doesn't fire the http request to Google to record the custom event.

Comment: Right I've just double checked and it appears the analytics script is not in our UAT environment, which is not right obviously. I will test it in live server and feed back.

Comment: My mistake, the anyalytics is in the UAT environment, back to square one.

Comment: I found the problem. The value was being parsed as a Strong, not an integer, which is needed for the analytics code. I will answer my own question in around 6 hours or so when I can. Thanks for your help Rory.

Comment: No worries. You should post that as a separate answer so that people who stumble accross this thread from google know how to fix it.